# Referring a input name as a label in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, label

I was trying to create labels for form inputs dynamically.

I wanted to set the 'name' attribute of the input as a label.

Is this a way to do it?

```
        inputCheckbox.attr("id", key).attr("name", key).appendTo("form");
        label.attr("name", inputCheckbox.attr("name"));
        form.append(label);
        form.append(inputCheckbox);
```

Comment: That depends.  Does it produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get it, but i always create my elements like this, and append them in one go :

```
var label = $('<label />', {'for': key, text: 'My label'}),
    input = $('<input />', {id: key, name: key, type: 'checkbox'});

form.append( label.append(input) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Label tag doesnt need to have `for` property, not `name` , so you code can be

```
var checkbox  = $('<input type="checkbox" />').attr( { name  : key, id : key } )
, label = $('<label />').attr('for', key).text(key).append(checkbox)

form.append(label)
```